# JS - Create new array based on original array randomly

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to create a function which takes an array, then returns a new array with a random amount of the items from the original array inside. Note that although it needs to be a random amount of the items from the original array, they still need to be in the same order. Any idea how to do this?

For example:

```js
const originalArr = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'hamster', 'parrot'];

/*
 Use Math.random() somehow so that each time you run a function it returns an array with a random amount of the items above inside it, e.g.

['cat', 'rabbit']
['dog', 'rabbit', 'hamster']
[]
['cat', 'parrot']
etc.
*/
```

Comment: Do you want all the possible subsequences to be equally likely? Do you want it to ever randomly return the entire sequence, or only proper subsequences?

Comment: Smells like a homework question with zero effort shown to attempt to solve any of it yourself. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: while this looks like a "do my homework" question, this looks so easy this is hardly a real academic assignment. Anyway, a guideline to solve it: iterate over the array and each iteration generate random integer [0,1]. If 1, add the element to the new array, 0 don't add it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt. Appears to work, but doesn't look very nice. Is there a better way? Something more functional JS style?

```js
const petsArr = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'hamster', 'parrot'];

const petsList = (petsListLength => () => {
  let currentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (petsListLength + 1));
  const randomPetsList = [];
  while (currentIndex < petsListLength) {
    randomPetsList.push(petsArr[currentIndex]);
    currentIndex += Math.floor(Math.random() * (petsListLength - 1)) + 1;
  }
  return randomPetsList;
})(petsArr.length);

console.log(petsList());
```

Comment: Feel free to ditch the IIFE, it doesn't do anything for you here. `forEach` will look a lot cleaner than manually checking and incrementing indicies